# Вертикальное движение объекта вместе с прокруткой страницы

Tags: javascript

Есть документ, у которого высота (как выдаёт консоль) - 3496. Есть полоса (слева), в которой я расположил кружочек, у этой полосы высота 90% от высоты **экрана**, пытаюсь сделать движение этого кружочка вместе с прокруткой страницы, но в итоге выходит совсем не то, либо не доходит до конца, либо наоборот выходит за линию. Есть такой код:

```js
cursor = $('.navigation-line .cursor');

documentH = $(document).height();
lineH = $('.navigation-line').height();

k = documentH / lineH;

step = 100 / k;

posY = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    posY += step;
    cursor.css('top', posY);
    console.log(posY);
  })
})
```

```css
.navigation-line {
  position: fixed;
  width: 10px;
  height: 95%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);
  /*border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);*/
  border-radius: 45px;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.navigation-line .cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: #f9f871;
  border-radius: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navigation-line">
  <div class="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще сразу переводить прокрутку в проценты:

```js
cursor = $('.navigation-line .cursor');

documentH = $(document).innerHeight();
lineH = $('.navigation-line').height();

k = documentH / lineH;

step = 100 / k;

posY = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    posY = $(this).scrollTop() / (documentH - $(window).innerHeight()) * 100 || 0;
    cursor.css('top', posY+'%');
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}

.navigation-line {
  position: fixed;
  width: 10px;
  height: 95%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);
  /*border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);*/
  border-radius: 45px;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.navigation-line .wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.navigation-line .cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #f9f871;
  border-radius: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navigation-line">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cursor"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```